# Is it possible to change the priority of a message in rsyslog?

Tags: rsyslog

I have a very dramatic and hypocondriac program, and it likes to spew alarming messages to syslog in cases when nothing really important happens. Besides, it sends them with priority "alert", so they float above the rest of messages of lower priority (anything lower than "err"), that I usually skip. The messages have a very specific format that I could filter or match, given the tools.

Is it possible, using rsyslog, to change the priority of these messages so they become "warning"? I don't want to get rid of them, just put them in their proper place.

Comment: Seen you want to change the given priority, the configuration should be on the program's configuration side, and it's program dependent.

It should be possible to archive something like that through rsyslog configuration, but not that advisable.

Comment: @user1293137, I've already checked that, and it doesn't seem possible. The program (vpnc) doesn't allow me to change its logging behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible from within [`rsyslog.conf(5)`](http://linux.frank4dd.com/en/man5/rsyslog.conf.htm) (the file to edit is `/etc/rsyslog.conf`). You should find out which "facility" your application sends its logs under and maybe choose to dump its logs in a separate file.